# Forge viewer and Revit nested families

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am having an issue with a particular model in the Forge viewer, sourced from a Revit file. I have some elements that contained nested families in Revit, and when I select these elements in Forge, the nested instance is treated as the leaf node. I want my viewer app to select its parent element because I have properties stored at the instance level that are not being detected when the nested instance is selected. Is there a consistent way to do this, given that any Revit-sourced element may contain X levels of nested instances?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can control the selection type through Viewer UI

[image]

There's also a sample extension focused on selecting parent nodes programmatically explained at https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-tab-cycle-selection

Comment: In my case none of the three selection modes selected the right node. I am able to traverse the tree to get parent/child nodes, but I don't see a way to detect if a node is generated from a Revit family instance or its nested family instance.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible sample model with the property you're trying to retrieve?
Please send it to aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com